# My ROC curve shows NAN for every fold except the 4th fold

Tags: binary, classification, roc

I have a binary classification dataset which helps me perform binary classification  on AF(Atrial Fibrillation) vs VT(Ventricular Tachycardia) datasets.But, my ROC plot configuration results are such that for every iteration it is yielding NAN and for the 4th one it shows 0.85. Do help me out on this.

```
 from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
#Preprocessing of NSR
data11 = pd.read_csv("NOM_ECG_ELEC_POTL_IIWaveExport.csv")
data11 = data11.drop('Unnamed: 2',axis=1)
data11.columns = ['date','values']
data11=data11.drop('date',axis=1)
data11=np.array_split(data11,6636)
#data =list(data11.values())
index_list = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0,len(data11)):
    indices = pd.DataFrame(data11[i])
    #indices = pd.DataFrame(indices)
    indices.columns =['value']
    indices.index = indices.value
    #indices = pd.concat([indices,data11],join ="inner",axis=1)
    #indices = indices.drop(['value','date'],axis=1)
    indices = indices.values.reshape(1,-1)
    indices =pd.DataFrame(indices)
    index_list = index_list.append(indices)




index_list = index_list.reset_index()
index_list=index_list.drop('index',axis=1)
index_list['output']=0


#Preprocessing of AF
data22 = pd.read_csv("VT.csv")
data22 = data22.drop('Unnamed: 2',axis=1)
data22.columns = ['date','values']
data22=data22.drop('date',axis=1)
data22=np.array_split(data22,4732)
#new_df_1 = pd.DataFrame()   
#data2 = data22.groupby(['date']).groups
index_list_1 = pd.DataFrame()
for j in range(0,len(data22)):
    indices = pd.DataFrame(data22[j])
    #indices = pd.DataFrame(indices)
    indices.columns =['value']
    indices.index = indices.value
    #indices = pd.concat([indices,data22],join ="inner",axis=1)
    #indices = indices.drop(['value','date'],axis=1)
    indices = indices.values.reshape(1,-1)
    indices =pd.DataFrame(indices)
    index_list_1 = index_list_1.append(indices)

index_list_1=index_list_1.fillna('9000')
index_list_1 = index_list_1.reset_index()
index_list_1=index_list_1.drop('index',axis=1)
index_list_1['output']=1

#Adding noise #Creating a random dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(8000,9000,size=(6636,1001)))
df['1001']=np.NAN
df.rename({'1001':'output'}, axis=1)
df=df.fillna('0')
#index_list_1.iloc[:,0:1001] = np.NAN
#cols1=index_list_1.iloc[:,1001:1002]
#y=cols1
#y.iloc[:,1001:1002]=np.NAN
#cols1=cols1.fillna('1')
#cols1 = index_list_1.iloc[:,0:1001]
#cols= index_list.fillna('9000')  
merged = pd.concat([index_list_1,index_list])
merged=merged.drop(merged.columns[-2],axis=1)
#total=pd.concat([index_list_1,df])

#total=pd.concat([merged,df])
#merged_1=shuffle(merged)
#degree=merged['output']
#degree=degree.fillna('1')
#merged=pd.concat([cols1,degree])
#merged=merged.fillna('9000')
#merged_1 = merged_1.reset_index()
#merged_1 = merged_1.drop(['index'],axis=1)
merged.to_csv("AF_Prediction.csv")

cols2=merged['output']
#cols1=merged['output']
#cols1=pd.Dataframe(cols1)
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
#Create training and testing variables
cols2=pd.DataFrame(cols2)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(merged,cols2, test_size=0.2)

y_train=pd.DataFrame(y_train)
#Instantiate Model
model = LogisticRegression()
#Hypertuning the Model
model= LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', dual=False, tol=0.0001, C=1.0)

#X_train.head()
#y_train.head()

#Fit Model
y_train=y_train.astype('bool')
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
# make class predictions for the testing set
y_pred_class = model.predict(X_test)
y_pred_class=pd.DataFrame(y_pred_class)
y_test=y_test.astype('bool')
y_pred_class=y_pred_class.astype('bool')
# calculate accuracy
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred_class,sample_weight=None))

#Confusion Matrix for the model

from sklearn.metrics import *
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterGrid
#param_grid = [{'kernel': ['linear']},{'kernel': ['rbf'], 'gamma': [1, 10]}]
#from sklearn.model_selection.ParameterGrid(param_grid)
cf=confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred_class)
print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred_class))
#Support Vector Machine -Grid Search
def svc_param_selection(X, y, nfolds):
    #Cs = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10]
    #gammas = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1]
    #param_grid = {'C': Cs, 'gamma' : gammas}
    param_grid = [{'kernel': ['linear']},{'kernel': ['rbf'], 'gamma': [1, 10]}]
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(svm.SVC(param_grid))
    grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
    grid_search.best_params_
    return grid_search.best_params_
best_params_=svc_param_selection(merged,cols2,10)
#Support Vector Machine classifier
#from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split  
#X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(cols, y, test_size = 0.50) 


from sklearn.svm import SVC  
svclassifier = SVC(kernel='rbf') 
svclassifier.fit(X_train, y_train)  
#Make prediction on SVM  
y_pred = svclassifier.predict(X_test)
y_pred=y_pred.reshape(-1,1)
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix,accuracy_score 
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred))  
print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred))  

#K-Cross validation
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
clf = SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
scores = cross_val_score(clf,X_train ,y_train , cv=10)

from scipy import interp
from itertools import cycle
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve,auc
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
tprs =[]
aucs= []
mean_fpr = np.linspace(0,1,100)
cv=KFold(n_splits=10)
i = 0
for train, test in cv.split(merged, cols2):
    probas_ = model.fit(merged.iloc[train], cols2.iloc[train]).predict_proba(merged.iloc[test])
    # Compute ROC curve and area the curve
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(cols2.iloc[test], probas_[:, 1])
    tprs.append(interp(mean_fpr, fpr, tpr))
    tprs[-1][0] = 0.0
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
    aucs.append(roc_auc)
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, lw=1, alpha=0.3,
             label='ROC fold %d (AUC = %0.2f)' % (i, roc_auc))

    i += 1
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], linestyle='--', lw=2, color='r',
         label='Chance', alpha=.8)

mean_tpr = np.mean(tprs, axis=0)
mean_tpr[-1] = 1.0
mean_auc = auc(mean_fpr, mean_tpr)
std_auc = np.std(aucs)
plt.plot(mean_fpr, mean_tpr, color='b',
         label=r'Mean ROC (AUC = %0.2f $\pm$ %0.2f)' % (mean_auc, std_auc),
         lw=2, alpha=.8)

std_tpr = np.std(tprs, axis=0)
tprs_upper = np.minimum(mean_tpr + std_tpr, 1)
tprs_lower = np.maximum(mean_tpr - std_tpr, 0)
plt.fill_between(mean_fpr, tprs_lower, tprs_upper, color='grey', alpha=.2,
                 label=r'$\pm$ 1 std. dev.')

plt.xlim([-0.05, 1.05])
plt.ylim([-0.05, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Receiver operating characteristic example')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.savefig('roc 10fold for vitals only xgb.png')
plt.show()

#auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred)
#plt.plot(fpr,tpr,label="data 1, auc="+str(auc))
#plt.legend(loc=4)
#plt.show()

 #fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_test, 
  model.predict_proba(x_test)[:,1])
   # Calculate Area under
   #for m in models:
   #   model = m['model'] # select the model
   #  model.fit(X_train, Y_train) # train the model
   # y_pred=model.predict(X_test) # predict the test data
   # Compute False postive rate, and True positive rate
    #fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_test, 
    model.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1])
    # Calculate Area under the curve to display on the plot
    #auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(Y_test,model.predict(X_test))
    # Now, plot the computed values
    #plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label='%s ROC (area = %0.2f)' % (m['label'], auc))

#plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label='%s ROC (area = %0.2f)' % (m['label'], auc)
```

)

Comment: You're not likely to get an answer unless you describe your problem in much more details. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @Calimo so I have saved an image under the URL.Please look into it and let me know.

Comment: Please include the code you use as text, that can be copy-pasted, not as an image. Also it doesn't show a good portion of your code and of your data so it's not very useful.

Comment: Hey so I have formatted the code.Could you please look into it?

Comment: I get an error: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` and if I fix it: `IOError: File NOM_ECG_ELEC_POTL_IIWaveExport.csv does not exist`. Please also make an effort to reduce your example to the minimum if you want an answer. This might also help you to figure it out by yourself.

Comment: That error is because the csv file is with me and not with you.If you want, I can send you the csv file and you can figure it out by givinge your email id